# In the books it is said that Urû'baen/Ilirea is placed under a slab of rock. How is it exactly placed?

Tags: inheritance-cycle

The doubt I'm having is if Urû'baen is:

A) just under a huge cantilever:
[image: cantilever]

B) just at the base of a huge cliff, like Minas Tirith:
[image: Minas-Tirith]

C) just inside a huge lightly eroded cave:
[image: cave urubaen]

D) just inside an eroded volcano caldera
[image: volcano city]

E) None of the previously mentioned (explain why+description+site).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q.** *Do you have any concept art of Urû'baen or Ilirea? We wouldn't find much and we want to do the capital city justice!*
>
> **Christopher Paolini:** *You can see the small painting of Ilirea/Urû'baen in this.*
> <sub><sup>[Per Twitter](https://twitter.com/paolini/status/712746482760175616)</sup></sub>
>
> [image]

The painting described seems to be this one from *Eldest*;

> "It depicted a beautiful, towering city built against an escarpment and caught in the ruddy light of a rising harvest moon."

---

And this is the image of the city from [The *Official Eragon Colouring Book*](https://www.paolini.net/works/official-eragon-coloring-book/)

[image]

---

Inheritance contains a fair description.

> “What interested him most, however, was not the wall or the buildings,
> but the fact that much of the city lay shadowed underneath a huge
> stone shelf, which must have been over half a mile wide and five
> hundred feet thick at its narrowest. **The overhang formed one end of a
> massive, sloping hill that stretched off to the northeast for several
> miles.** Atop the craggy lip of the shelf stood another wall, like that
> which surrounded the city, and several thick watchtowers.
>
> **At the back of the cavelike recess underneath the shelf was an
> enormous citadel adorned with a profusion of towers and parapets.** The
> citadel rose high above the rest of the city, high enough that it
> almost scraped the underside of the shelf. Most intimidating of all
> was the gate set within the front of the fortress: a great, gaping
> cavern that looked large enough for Saphira and Thorn to walk through
> side by side.”

Comment: Twitter edited for ease of reading.

Comment: This looks like a mix of A and C.

Comment: Isn't it a bit impractical to have the city shrouded in shadows 22 hours of the day?

Comment: I'd be more concerned about the fact that it's held up by magic

Comment: Well, I always thought that the overhang didn't cover more than a third of the city.
However with the setting of the image, the streets must need streetlights at all hours of the day (or those flameless torches). Otherwise, the criminality rate would shoot up through the ceiling (pun intended). Also, it's difficult to do things in the darkness, like distinguishing between fellow soldiers of the Empire or those of the Varden.